# Firebase: Check for changes in JSON and automatically send notification

Tags: android, json, firebase, push-notification

### UPDATE:

Ok so from all the comments I got convinced that using Firebase is the best solution for a number of reasons but how would I check for that change (`canceled == yes`) in my json file from firebase and automatically send the notification if the course is canceled.

**Sample JSON response:**

```
        {
            "class" : "Class",
            "time" : "00:00",
            "trainer" : "T",
            "canceled" : ""
        },
        {
            "class" : "Class",
            "time" : "00:00",
            "trainer" : "T",
            "canceled" : ""
        }
```

---

### INITIAL QUESTION

I am parsing a json api and one of the fields is called `canceled`.

I would like my app to set a notification whenever that `canceled` key has a value of `yes` and so far it's easy, just create a simple notification like in the [android developer topic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and if `canceled == yes` update the `Builder` and then `notify();`.

The issue here is how can I keep checking for changes in the json after the app has been closed and set the notification ?

> I have access to the server and make changes to the api if required.

Can I do this without the help of any third party services?

Comment: run a background service which will hit the server and keep on checking server response.

Comment: @NileshDeokar I will look at the documentation but never done it before. Could you give me an example of how it should be done? Thank you.

Comment: Developing a full push architecture can be very tough, i suggest you use something like https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: @SujalMandal I took a look at firebase but since this is the only use case scenario for my notifications I thought it could be done without involving any third party services.

Comment: The best way to achieve this would be to get let the server send a push-notification whenever there is a change, using services like firebase. The other thing you can do, though is not the recommended one, is start a android [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and keep calling the api, and checking the response. Services are android components that can function in background .

Comment: @Alin there Is absolutely no need to fear using firebase notification services. It is entirely free and scales basically to any size. Furthermore `cancelled` suggests that this is something which happens once. To run multiple requests until something is cancelled will only put extra strain on your server. Additionally there are new restrictions on background services since Oreo [link](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c)  so you might as well already write it optimally.

Comment: @Lukasz I am already convinced that is what I should do. Now what I want to figure out is how to check for that change in my json file from firebase and automatically send the notification if the course is canceled.

Comment: @Alin You wouldn't want to check it from your json. Since you control the server here is what you have to do. You have a user which cancels something (customer?) and a user which needs to be informed about the cancellation (service provider?). When the customer sends his request for cancellation you do not only store it in your database but also send a FCM request to the service provider to look up changes on the server. You then display the result of that request in the same way as you probably already do.

Comment: @SujalMandal I have updated my question after deciding to use Firebase

Comment: @ZeekHuge  I have updated my question after deciding to use Firebase. Thank you

Comment: You will need to use firebase admin APIs : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/ . Use these APIs in your server code to send a notification to your client device.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. where you able to find a way to monitor the change in th JSON and then trigger the Notification? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Sujal mentioned With Android O you have restriction on running background service for a long time. So It's better move this thing to server side. Whenever there is a change in the status i.e. Whenever key `canceled` becomes `yes` send a notification to android device which would show the Notification.

Ref : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/
Ref : https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb

Comment: Ok, this looks promising, but how do I check for that change in my json file from firebase and automatically send the notification if the course is canceled.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: how's value getting changed in firebase ? Who is updating it ?

Comment: That json api is generated from a website I created and the value is changed from the CMS. When a course is canceled, the admin changes the cancel field in the CMS from no to yes and the json gets updated.

Comment: yeah then from CMS you must be calling Server api via which value gets updated. So on same event you can add code for sending notification to android device.